# Nozzle hitting bed corner before it stars printing

Tags: bed-leveling, homing, artillery-hornet

I just got this Artillery Hornet printer. I am new to the 3D printing but the printer is not new.

The glass bed was leveled from the Marlin firmware menu (**Motion > Bed leveling > Level corners**) and I manually adjusted the distance of all corners to be exactly 0.1 mm from the nozzle.

The printer works fine but I am not satisfied with the glass bed which does have adhesion problems with PLA, it is difficult to print the first layer with a reasonably low temperature for the bed and filament.

What I wanted to do was to install a new PEI bed, but faced the following problem: before the printer started printing from G-code, the head would go to the bottom right corner and hit the glass bed with the nozzle once. Then it continues on the appropriate level. Since the nozzle is made of brass and the bed is glass it won't do any noticeable damage to the bed surface.

However, I am not entirely sure if it is safe for the nozzle or PEI that I am about to install. Is it normal that the printer would do something like this or does it need to be adjusted/fixed somehow?

Is this common or is this on purpose?

My understanding is that before printing, the head is parked at the home position. Therefore, the Z-axis limit sensor needs to be reached. This is the moment when it happens. This printer is not equipped with Automatic Bed Leveling (ABL).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with your printer but I've had that happen as part of a filament heating routine where the nozzle touches the bed while the extruder heats up. The intention was to stop the filament from leaking out. In my case, it was part of the start G-code set up in my slicer.

You don't mention the slicer you are using so here is where you find it in the two I use:

Prusa Slicer: **Printer settings tab > Left panel Custom G-code**

Cura: **Settings menu > Printer > Manage printers > Machine settings > Start G-code.**